# Msal Angular issue with Angular 9 with login redirect flow

Tags: angular, authentication, angular9, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the below packages in my Angular 9 project:

```
"@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0",
"msal": "^1.3.2",
```

and my app module contains the below code:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
auth: {
clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/",
validateAuthority: true,
redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/callback",
navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
},
cache: {
cacheLocation : "sessionStorage",
}
}, {
popUp: false,
consentScopes: [ "user.read", "openid", "profile"],
extraQueryParameters: {}
})
]
```

I have a route that has MsalGuard, and I'm trying to login the user via LoginRedirect instead of popup.

Here's what i see in the browser's console:

```
TypeError: this.authResponseCallback is not a function
at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.authErrorHandler (VM68 vendor.js:108949)
at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenInteractive (VM68 vendor.js:109054)
at MsalService.push../node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js.UserAgentApplication.loginRedirect (VM68 vendor.js:108967)
at MsalGuard. (VM68 vendor.js:106305)
at Generator.next ()
at VM68 vendor.js:131946
at new ZoneAwarePromise (VM71 polyfills.js:973)
at __awaiter (VM68 vendor.js:131942)
at MsalGuard.loginInteractively (VM68 vendor.js:106295)
at MsalGuard.canActivate (VM68 vendor.js:106321)
```

Any idea what am i missing?